# aws:check if a Cognito user is authenticated in a lambda function

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is it it possible to find out if a user has authenticated in Cognito pool from a Node.js Lambda function?
User name (alias) is known
Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a lambda function that should only be executed by a user authenticated through Cognito, you should be looking into using API Gateway

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html